# 3-manifolds with certain fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $M$ is a 3-manifold with $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Is it true that $M$ is diffeomorphic to a lens space $L(p,q)$?

Comment: Take a lens space and take a pointt away from it. The result is a 3-manifold with the same fundamental group.

Comment: you probably forgot to add the hypothesis that the manifold is closed, as evinced by my example above. You should then google for «fake lens spaces».

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez This is in the setting of 3-manifolds. Fake lens spaces are higher-dimensional phenomena. It is true that a closed 3-manifold with fundamental group $\mathbb Z/p$ is homeomorphic to some $L(p,q)$.

Comment: Use the elliptization theorem to realize $M$ as a quotient of $S^3$ by an orthogonal matrix of order $p$. Use linear algebra to conjugate this to the desired form and see that $M$ is an $L(p,q)$. There is surely a more classical proof that such a manifold is homeomorphic to $L(p,q) \# S$ where $S$ is a homotopy 3-sphere but I do not know the argument.

Comment: @MikeMiller, well, the intention was for the OP to google and find that fact!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ah, sorry (: